# Remove load average from time string displayed in mode-line

Tags: mode-line-format

I like to show date and time in the mode-line. I currently have this in my .emacs file: 

`(setq display-time-day-and-date t)
(setq display-time-format "%I:%M %p %e %b %y %_5j")
(display-time)`

How do I remove the cpu load average which always appears at the end of the time string? I've tried setting the variable `format-time-string` without any change in the load average display.

I've combed through the docs and also looked at `global-mode-string` without help.

As phils points out below, `(setq display-time-default-load-average nil)` addresses the issue.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, after startup, it will be 12hr format without load-average for a while, after that it will change back to the format that when I didn't put the config line in my init.el which contains the load-average.

Comment: It haven't worked for either. But I notice that I had (display-time-mode) not (display-time) It should be only (display-time).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the variable `display-time-default-load-average`

n.b. I found that very quickly using <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to search for "load average".